# how to send https GET request with oauth

Tags: ios, json, swift, oauth, get

i build project swift with OAuth and i already got Acces Token from my API Login and then i want get data from API JSon with my acces token. so, how to use OAuth get request http method with OAuth and my acces token

i have json parse standar without OAuth

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://conversation.8villages.com/1.0/contents/articles?state=published")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data,response,error in

        guard error == nil && data != nil else {
            print("error", error!)
            return
        }

        let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse

        if httpStatus!.statusCode == 200
        {
            if data?.count != 0
            {
              let responString = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)
                print(responString)
            }
            else{
                print("No got data from URL")
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("error httpstatus code is ", httpStatus!.statusCode)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

i'm used Librabry https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift

in there i got Signed Request (Readme.md) like this

```
oauthswift.client.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~",
 success: { response in
let dataString = response.string
print(dataString)
},
failure: { error in
print(error)
}
)
```

but im confused how to add my Acces Token, Consumer Key and My Consumer Secret to acces my API JSON

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the access token, it seems you have already used your consumer key and consumer secret and you are authenticated. You need to pass the bearer access token in the authorization header of API get call.

Comment: how to pas bearer token sir? please tell me :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with OAuthSwift framework but I guess the error is in the following row:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Maybe it should be:

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(tokenType + " " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
```

Where `tokenType` for a OAuth Authorization Code grant type always is the string `Bearer` and `accessToken` is of course the access token you have got from earlier.

EDIT:
Compare with the Microsoft Azure AD:

```
GET /v1.0/me/messages
Host: https://graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUz...
```

Comment: sir, my accesToken is 2 key like Token Key and Token Secret. so. how to add both them?